# How to grant ACE to Movavi Screen Recorder?

Tags: screen-capture, video-capture

My Movavi Screen Recorder doesn't record sound from application. When I press the loudspeaker icon, the following window appears

[image]

What does it mean (why not write friendly error messages)? And how to fullfill it's requirements?

Pressing `Open System Preferences` doesn't help. It opens system preferences with nothing like `ACE` inside.

Comment: Movavi seems to install the Audio Capture Engine “ACE” byRogue Amoeba's - it’s a audio handling component. [Here are step by step instructions](https://rogueamoeba.com/support/knowledgebase/?showArticle=ACE-BigSur) on how to install it.

Comment: That can happen if you have SIP switched off. It can't correctly ask for permissions in the system pref.